# Disable scrolling via dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I would like to disable scrolling once a button is pressed. I already found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4770179/1394336) and it's really good - but the user is still able to scroll by marking something on the page and drag it to the top/bottom of the browser.

This code resets the scroll position as quick as possible, but the scrolling is still visible (and this solutions appears a bit dirty)

```
var pageYOffset = window.pageYOffset;
setInterval(function () { window.scrollTo(0, pageYOffset) }, 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try by [disabling text selection highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting) when scrolling is in disabled state.

try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Ku26/24/)

in disable_scroll() add

```
$("html").addClass("diableSelection");
```

and in enable_scroll() add

```
$("html").removeClass("diableSelection");
```

where .diableSelection will be

```
.diableSelection {
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, my questions seems to be over simplified: I have an element on my site which has to be draggable :/ But that's my fault, you answered my question anyway

Comment: maybe it's the fiddle, but it doesn't work: the page scrolls up/down when i drag my mouse outside of its region...